# Confused about Using Modified Bessel Function To Solve Partial Differential Equation

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations, bessel-functions

The form of Modified Bessel Function is expressed as:

$$\frac{d^2p(r)}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{dp(r)}{dr}-(\alpha^2+\frac{v^2}{r^2})p(r)=0$$
Where $\alpha$ and $v$ both are real numbers.
Its general solution could be expressed as:
$$p(r)=c_1I_v(\alpha x)+c_2K_v(\alpha x)$$

Recent I met a problem about Modified Bessel Function that I didn't understand very well. See below.

$$\frac{d^2p(r,t)}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{dp(r,t)}{dr}=\frac{1}{c}\frac{dp(r,t)}{dt}$$

Where $p$ is a function of $r$ and $t$. My purpose is to get the solution of $p$. In order to solve it, firstly Laplace transform with respect with $t$ is performed. Therefore,
$$\frac{d^2P(r,s)}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{dP(r,s)}{dr}=\frac{1}{c}[s*P(r,s)-p(r,0)]$$
With the initial boundary value $p(r,0)=0$, we have
$$\frac{d^2P(r,s)}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{dP(r,s)}{dr}=(\sqrt \frac{s}{c})^2P(r,s)$$
Based on the solution to Modified Bessel Function, we have
$$P(r,s)=c_1I_0(r\sqrt\frac{s}{c})+c_2K_0(r\sqrt\frac{s}{c})$$

However, the correct solution to this PDE is
$$\frac{sP^"(r,s)}{p_0}=-\frac{K_0(r\sqrt\frac{s}{c})}{K_0(a\sqrt\frac{s}{c})}$$
Where $a$ is a real number.

I don't know why there is such a big difference in my solution and the correct solution.

I will appreciate it if you can leave your valuable viewpoint or comment.

Thank you.

Kl.

Comment: $P''(r,s)$ is  $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}P(r, s)$ ?

Comment: YES. $P^"(r,s)$ is $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}P(r,s)$